# How can I programatically select the node template to render a node in Drupal 7

Tags: views, 7, theming

I have a node--mynodetype.tpl.php, the problem that I have is that I have a module to show public contents.

In this module I need to render something completely different to what is in node--mynodetype.tpl.php.

So I was thinking to create a file named, for example, node--mynodetype-public.tpl.php but I was googling and I can't find a function to select one node template or other node tpl.

Is this any function to select wich node template to render?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning pages to templates in Drupal 7 (like in WordPress)](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13380/assigning-pages-to-templates-in-drupal-7-like-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 2):

Unless I am missing something here, this is a classic job for `hook_preprocess_node()`, eg...

```
function YOURMODULEORTHEME_preprocess_node(&variables) {

  if ( /* whatever logic */ ) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__YOURNODETYPE_public';
  }

  // other preprocessing here

}
```

...which would cause Drupal to look for a `node--YOURNODETYPE-public.tpl.php` template when whatever logic was true.

Read [Working with Template Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/223440) and [Theme Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) for a lot more info on all of this.