# How to create a theme that handle articles in different categories?

Tags: theming

I am creating a theme that has many categories which have two types of handling articles. 
For example:

- Categories (A,B,C,D,E) will show articles in two column
- Categories (F,G) will show articles in only one column
- These articles will show in home page in a different manner

I had already created page.tpl.php as well as page--front.tpl.php, I also created a node--article.tpl.php. So am I able to do this with drupal theming? or it is not possible?

Comment: My advice is that you are thinking about this in the wrong way. Your objectives are not related to themeing. At this stage, you should be working from a default theme. You can worry about presentation later - after you have your data defined and in place. Look into the taxonomy and views modules for now to get yourself started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you ought to use Drupal's taxonomy system for creating the categories. This is better than content types, because your articles aren't really different types of content... you just want them to display differently.

So first, you [create a vocabulary](https://drupal.org/node/23405) called "Categories" with Terms "A, B, C, D, E, F, & G". Then, on your article content type, you [add a taxonomy field](http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/taxonomy/content), allowing you to choose which term to associate with a specific article.

Finally, you need a way to vary the display depending on the category chosen. I like [this solution, which uses preprocessing to supply per-term template suggestions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/13383/11788). You could tweak his example, to set template suggestions for one or two columns like so (note, this isn't running code... just an example):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Get the Term ID from the "Categories" vocab for the current node.
  $current_term_tid = ... // (figure out where that data is in the $variables)
  $one_column_tids = array(...) // (list the tids for terms you want to display in one column)

  if (in_array($current_term_tid, $one_column_tids)) {
    // Tell Drupal to use the 'one_column_template' template if it exists.
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'one_column_template';
  }
  else {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'two_column_template';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to create different content types for each type article.

I would then use [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) and [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) to create the page. Create a view for each subset of article types then place each view in your panels page.

You could also do it with a theme by creating what panels creates for you but you would still need a `view` with a `block` setting and then places the `views block` in the correct section of your site and set the block to only show on the home page.

The views+panels is a much cleaner implementation that is theme independent.